# NextJS url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default().URL is undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I apply URL.createObjectURL I get an error url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default().URL is undefined how to solve?
Did not find information on this issue.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.0",
    "@react-spring/native": "^9.5.5",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.5.5",
    "@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.5",
    "@rooks/use-window-size": "^4.11.2",
    "@types/node": "20.3.3",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "create-object-url": "^1.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "localStorage": "^1.0.4",
    "next": "13.4.8",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^8.1.0",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "nvm": "0.0.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.6.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.16",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  },
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.